# Identity Server 4 - cancel redirect to login and return 401 instead

Tags: redirect, identityserver4, unauthorized

I had an ASP.NET Core 2 web app *without* Identity Server where I configured the automatic challange of unauthenticated HTTP requests to not redirect the user to the login page and just return 401 instead:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
        {
            config.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```

How can I achieve the same with Identity Server 4 integration? I tried to use the same code inside the *AddOpenIdConnect* configuration method:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
    {
        ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    [...]
})
```

It doesn't work though, the server returns a 302 anyway...

Comment: Did u get answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 7):

It's too late I guess, but following worked for me. if someone has similar issue. **(context.HandleResponse(); is important in OP case)**

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                 {
                     if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
                     {
                         if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                         {
                             context.ProtocolMessage.State = options.StateDataFormat.Protect(context.Properties);
                             context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                             context.Response.Headers["Location"] = context.ProtocolMessage.CreateAuthenticationRequestUrl();
                         }
                         context.HandleResponse();
                     }
                     return Task.CompletedTask;
                 };
```

Comment: That should be made an accepted answer, works fine with .net core 5.0.